# unable to access UNC drive from Bash Script .sh

Tags: bash, cygwin, windows-server-2008

Trying to access network drive (UNC) from the bash script. The network drive needs username and password. 
i Can access UNC by running some individual commands like CD, net use .However unable to execute from a script.
follows below steps
1) Mount the drive to x drive by using below command from 
 Command : `net use x: \\\\Server_name\\Directory /user:users pass` /PERSISTENT:YES
Result :Sucess mounted x drive 
2) test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /cygdrive/x
count_node1 = cat a.log b.log.1 v.log.2 |grep "&&&&" | sort -k1,2 | grep -c 'word' 
#count_node1="got it"
echo helloworld
echo $count_node1
#end
```

Result: helloWorld
: No such file or directory/x
*count_node1: command not found*

3)Further, If I run each line from Cygwin individually it is working perfectly.

trying bash profile for first time really confused.

Comment: try `count_node=$(grep '&&&&' a.log b.log .... | sort ...| grep ..)` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

See syntax of your shell (bash). Correct:

```
count_node1=$(cat a.log b.log.1 v.log.2 |grep "&&&&" | sort -k1,2 | grep -c 'word')
```

or

```
count_node1=$(grep '&&&&' a.log b.log.1 v.log.2 |sort -k1,2 | grep -c 'word')
```

Comment: : Not sure what you mean by "See syntax of your shell", but only `csh` allows spaces around the `=` sign (and just when using `set var = val`). For `bash,ksh,sh,zsh,etc`, variable assingments are `varName="value"`. Learn to test your answers before posting them. Can't upvote this as is. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks for optimising the Syntax. Can you help me in accessing UNC path(//server/folder) from the shell script ? UNC path needs LDAP credentials to access the drive.

Comment: Thanks #@shellter. Just correct one problem of the question, without run it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The order matter with net use:

`net use x: \\\\Server_name\\Directory pass /user:users`

Comment: Net use works fine but however,  I am not able to access from the shell script. but the individual command like ls /cygdrive/x or cd cygdrive/x   working from cygwin terninal but not from .sh file why ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *carriage return* characters from the ends of your script's lines, i. e. save it in `unix` instead of `dos` file format.